# Combining Unique Items From Arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a data set that I am querying. The data looks like this:

```
db.activity.insert(
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5908e64e3b03ca372dc945d5"),
        "startDate" : ISODate("2017-05-06T00:00:00Z"),
        "details" : [
            {
                "code" : "2",
                "_id" : ObjectId("5908ebf96ae5003a4471c9b2"),
                "walkDistance" : "03",
                "jogDistance" : "01",
                "runDistance" : "08",
                "sprintDistance" : "01"
            }
        ]
    }
)

db.activity.insert(
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58f79163bebac50d5b2ae760"),
        "startDate" : ISODate("2017-05-07T00:00:00Z"),
        "details" : [
            {
                "code" : "2",
                "_id" : ObjectId("58f7948fbebac50d5b2ae7f2"),
                "walkDistance" : "01",
                "jogDistance" : "02",
                "runDistance" : "09",
                "sprintDistance" : ""
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

My desired output looks as such:

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "uniqueValues": [
      "03",
      "01",
      "08",
      "02",
      "09"
    ]
  }
]
```

In order to do that, I've developed the following code:

```
db.activity.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            "walk": [
                {$unwind: '$details'},
                {$group: {_id: null, uniqueValues: {$addToSet: "$details.walkDistance"}}}
            ], "jog": [
                {$unwind: '$details'},
                {$group: {_id: null, uniqueValues: {$addToSet: "$details.jogDistance"}}}
            ], "run": [
                {$unwind: '$details'},
                {$group: {_id: null, uniqueValues: {$addToSet: "$details.runDistance"}}}
            ], "sprint": [
                {$unwind: '$details'},
                {$group: {_id: null, uniqueValues: {$addToSet: "$details.sprintDistance"}}}
            ]
        }
    }])
```

However, I am still getting 4 different facets with their own `_id: null` and `uniqueValues` array. How do I change the query so that they all included in a single array, and the `""` is also excluded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$facet` really is not the best thing to use here. You should really just be applying [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) and filtering down the result with [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/):

```
db.activity.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "unique": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": {
          "$setDifference": [
            { "$concatArrays": [ 
              "$details.walkDistance",
              "$details.jogDistance",
              "$details.runDistance",
              "$details.sprintDistance"
            ]},
            []
          ]
        },
        "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$this", "" ] }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$unique" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "uniqueArray": { "$addToSet": "$unique" }  
  }}
])
```

Returns the result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : null,
    "uniqueArray" : [ 
        "09", 
        "03", 
        "01", 
        "02", 
        "08"
    ]
}
```

So after bringing all the array values into a single array using [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/), you apply [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) to reduce the list to the "unique" values. The [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) removes the `""` values you don't want.

Then it's just a matter of applying [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on the singular and reduced list and bringing it back together in the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to only keep unique values across documents.

You could also just [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) only and then [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), but the other operators don't really cost much and reduce some of the load by already narrowing down to "unique" within the document before you get to the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). So it's better to do it that way.

Really this can even be broken down futher, to simply [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) and [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) since we are talking about "sets" afterall:

```
db.activity.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "unique": {
      "$setDifference": [
        { "$setUnion": [ 
          "$details.walkDistance",
          "$details.jogDistance",
          "$details.runDistance",
          "$details.sprintDistance"
        ]},
        [""]
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$unique" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "uniqueArray": { "$addToSet": "$unique" }  
  }}
])
```

And that means that the overall statement becomes compatible back to MongoDB 2.6, or would be if all the forms such as `$details.walkDistance` were written out in their longer form using `$map`:

```
  "$setDifference": [
    { "$setUnion": [ 
      { "$map": { "input": "$details", "as": "d", "in": "$$d.walkDistance" } },
      { "$map": { "input": "$details", "as": "d", "in": "$$d.jogDistance" } },
      { "$map": { "input": "$details", "as": "d", "in": "$$d.runDistance" } },
      { "$map": { "input": "$details", "as": "d", "in": "$$d.sprintDistance" } }
    ]},
    [""]
  ]
```

On the other hand running [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) causes a "brute force" parse through the whole collection for every property from within the array, and `$unwind` being processed on each of those passes. So it's a really inefficient way to obtain the result. So don't do it that way.

Comment: I am going to post another question directly related to this answer, specifically about adding `$match` statements, as simply adding them to the beginning of the answer does not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809451/add-match-statement-to-query-containing-concatarrays